# Arduino IRremote library weird behavior

Tags: arduino, avr

I realize that this is a very specific issue, but here it goes...

I'm using the [IRremote](https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote) library to be able to control a LED screen with a remote control. This is my implementation of `loop()`.

```
void loop()
{
    if (irrecv.decode(&res))
    {
        Serial.println(res.value, HEX);
        controller.takeAction(res.value);
        irrecv.resume();                                   
    }

    // controller.iterate();
}
```

Notice that the last line is commented out. This is what is causing the problems... Somehow, when I do call this function, the IR codes returned by the decoder rarely make sense. Nothing interesting happens in that function. There's no interaction whatsoever with the IRremote library in this function.

When I comment the call, I get the following output:

```
FF30CF
FF30CF
FF30CF
FF30CF
FF30CF
FF30CF
FF30CF
FF30CF
```

The decoder gets it right on all occasions. However, with the call uncommented, I get this ouput:

```
661CB9CF   // WRONG
2DE59485   // WRONG
E007A367   // WRONG
FF         // WRONG
FF30CF     // OK
FF         // WRONG
FF30C      // WRONG
FF30CF     // OK
33         // WRONG
FF30CF     // OK
700EEBE2   // WRONG
E007A367   // WRONG
FF30CF     // OK
FF30CF     // OK
E7         // WRONG
5E55E51A   // WRONG
```

It's a mess...

This wasn't the first issue I had though. Previously, I had encapsulated the library calls in a class-member. For some reason, this caused the decoding to break down entirely. There was a 1 second delay on every button-press, and the codes were never right. What's going on behind the scenes that could be causing such behavior?

Comment: `Serial.println()` places characters in a buffer, which are then sent via interrupts. Is your iterate() function interfering with interrupts in some way?

Comment: @UncleO I don't think it has anything to do with the `println` statements. It's not a matter of the values being printed wrong, because the actions taken by `takeAction` also reflect the values themselves being wrong... The answer below by mpflaga also suggests that interrupts are causing this, so you might be on the right track. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

The IRremote library is interrupted driven. Where it appears clear that

```
controller.iterate();
```

is blocking those interrupts, causing the timing of the irrecv interrupt.

There are several forks of the IRremote, where the original is based on a periodic interrupt that polls the input pin. It has a config file that can adjust the period as to be more lossy, but be more tolerant of delayed interrupts.

Additionally there other forks (such as by microtherion) that alternatively use PCINT changes that may be more responsive.

Other than that the best solution is to dig into Class of the controller object as to determine why it is blocking interrupts.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I don't have access to my setup right now but I will look into the config and forks. I wrote the Controller class myself, and the classes that support it, none of which are using interrupts. If interrupts are being used, it must be by the FastLED library that is called in the `iterate` function. However, FastLED is also called by `takeAction`, which doesn't screw things up. It still doesn't add up...

Comment: The IRremote library pushes the time interval between the change of each IR toggle into an array of (in shirriff's original fork) or 50 periods or bits. It may be that your LED shifting routing takes longer than period between IR packets being resent. Causing buffer over runs.